# Error to replace letters to other

Tags: string, excel, vba, replace

Why does this code not work properly? the task is to replace (str. and strasse) from the right position only when the occur first. In test its doing nothing.

I guess the error is in this line: `x.Value = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(x.Value), strArr(b), "straße", 1, 1))` where is the error in.

```
Sub strreplace()
Dim strArr As Variant
Dim b As Byte
Dim x As Range

strArr = Array("str.", "strasse", """")

For Each x In Selection.Cells
For b = 0 To UBound(strArr)
x.Value = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(x.Value), strArr(b), "straße", 1, 1))
Next b
Next x
End Sub
```

The second code I have tested is:

```
Sub strReplace()
Dim strArr As Variant
Dim b As Byte

strArr = Array("str.", "strasse", """")

For Each x In Selection
For b = 0 To UBound(strArr)
If InStrRev(x, strArr(b)) > 0 Then
Selection.Replace x, Replace(x, strArr(b), "straße", InStrRev(x,  strArr(b)))
End If
Next b
Next
End Sub

This code transform example:
```

"Lessonstrasse" in straße without Lesson...

Comment: *from the right position only whenn the occur first* -> Do you mean if `.str` or `.strasse` are the **right-most** words in the cell value?

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: Also, in your first macro, you are searching for `strArr(b)` in the **REVERSED** string in `x`.  You will never find it, unless you search for the reverse of `strArr(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've reversed the string you're searching, then the string being sought needs reversed as well.  So `"strArr(b)"` should become `StrReverse(strArr(b))`. The code below corrects this, with a change of array text to demonstrate.

Also, I notice your replacement text doesn't have a dot.  You may want to use `".straße"` instead of `"straße"`.  Also, you may find a user defined function more convenient for this, but of course, I don't know you're usage context.

```
Sub strreplace()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strArr As Variant
    Dim b As Byte
    Dim x As Range

    strArr = Array(".Ext1", ".Ext2")

    For Each x In Selection.Cells
        For b = 0 To UBound(strArr)
            x.Value2 = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(x.Value2), StrReverse(strArr(b)), "straße", 1, 1))
        Next b
    Next x
End Sub
```

Result...

[image]